# AJAX Response Wrapper

Tags: javascript

I wrote a small web request response wrapper to print out data from the backend, but I was hoping to find a better way as I am passing this to some developers and want to make their life easier.

This is my current wrapper

```
class Req {
    static log(req){
       return req()
          .done(function(data){
              console.log(data);
          })
          .fail(function(err){
              console.log(err);
          });
    }
}
```

All of my backend commands are static functions of some class. In order to send the funtion to `Req.log` I must use `bind`

`Req.log(BackendRoute.someCommand.bind(BackendRoute, {param1:1, param2:2}));`

Is there any way to send the function `BackendRoute.someCommand` without having to bind `BackendRoute` to the function?

This is what `BackendRoute` looks like

```
class BackendRoute {
    static someCommand(params){
       return BackendRoute.post(params);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fat arrow. It is a new function you are creating but it is clearer and still short:

```
Req.log(() => BackendRoute.someCommand({param1:1, param2:2}));
```

Comment: This is the least verbose approach, assuming you don't want `BackendRoute.someCommand` to be bound from the start